# In Capybara, how to make #find wait for DIFFERENT element with the SAME class to appear?

Tags: javascript, ruby, capybara

In Capybara, you can implicitly wait for an element to appear with

`find('.slide', visible: true)`

How can I detect that I new/different slide is visible? So I can do something like this which currently doesn't work (Capybara finds the current .slide before it is hidden instead of waiting for the current slide to hide and new slide to show):

```
3.times do
  find('.slide').fill_in('image[description]', with: 'foo')
  click_link 'Next slide'
end
```

### For example

I have markup like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="slide active" style="background: green;">
    </li>
    <li class="slide" style="background: blue;">
    </li>
    <li class="slide" style="background: pink;">
    </li>
</ul>
<a href="#" class="next-slide">Next slide</a>
```

I have some javascript to hide the active slide and fade in the next slide:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.next-slide').click(function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $activeSlide = $('.slide.active');
        $activeSlide.next().addClass('active');
        $activeSlide.hide().removeClass('active');
    });   
});
```

Complete JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/epylinkn/fQHmf/1/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is probably to give each slide an additional class or id - ie

```
<ul>
    <li class="slide slide-0 active" style="background: green;">
    </li>
    <li class="slide slide-1" style="background: blue;">
    </li>
    <li class="slide slide-2" style="background: pink;">
    </li>
</ul>

3.times do |i|
  find(".slide-#{i}", visible: true).fill_in('image[description]', with: 'foo')
  click_link 'Next slide'
end
```

Comment: I think that a method that requires to change source code of a tested app can't be called simplest.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it without modification of app's source code:

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  find("ul > .slide.active:nth-child(#{i})").fill_in('image[description]', with: 'foo')
  click_link 'Next slide'
end
```

`find("ul > .slide.active:nth-child(#{i})")` will wait till `i`th slide will become active which is what you want.

This code assumes that first 3 children of `ul` are slides.